# Automating Define Projection within Python script tool?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, python-script-tool

How would I automate the Define Projection tool so that I can just enter my layer each time?

I have it as a script in toolbox, but I am unsure how to set it so I can just input my layer as GetParameterAsText

Here is the script. I want to replace the "forest.shp" with a layer of my own choosing each time

```
 # set local variables
 inDataset = "forest.shp"
 coordinateSystem ="GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]"

arcpy.DefineProjection_management(inDataset, coordinateSystem)
```

Comment: You could make the input to your tool a Model Parameter. Upon running the tool, it will ask for you input just like when you run it from the Toolbox. Do you know the you can run it as a "batch" as well by right clicking on the Define Projection tool.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it in python by adding

```
inDataset   = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
```

here is that example.

[Understanding_script_tool_parameters](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Understanding_script_tool_parameters/001500000007000000/)

Then add as a script tool. 
[Adding_a_script_tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Adding_a_script_tool/00150000001r000000/)

Or just set the model param as MLowry suggested. That is probably quicker and easier.

Answer (score 4):

your .py file must be :

```
import arcpy 
try:
   coordinateSystem ="GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]"
   fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #your featureclass file
   dessr = arcpy.Describe(fc)
   srr = dessr.spatialReference
   arcpy.AddMessage("Your previous projection: %s" % (srr))

   arcpy.DefineProjection_management(fc, coordinateSystem)
   arcpy.AddMessage("Your process finished...")
except:
   arcpy.AddMessage("Cant trasformed new projection")
```

and then follow theJones direction....